# spreadsheet program that supports reading HDF5 files

Tags: spreadsheet, hdf5

Is there any spreadsheet program that supports reading HDF5 files ?;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you already tried HDFview?

its tabular view is quite similar to a spreadsheet application, you can also save to text file and then open it with a more standard spreadsheet application if you prefer:

http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/hdfview/UsersGuide/ug05spreadsheet.html#ug05save

Answer (score 1):

You can download HDFview here:
http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/hdfview/index.html